# C# - Datagridview columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` in a WinForm. I fill the `DataGridView` from a database table. I was wondering if there is any way to program my `DataGridView` so that I can choose which columns I want the gridview to show at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is "yes".

In the first instance you need to set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the `DataGridView` to false then you can control which columns get displayed.

In the past I've created a context menu for the DGV:

```
ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
foreach (var column in this.dataGridView.Columns)
{
    this.AddContextMenuItem(ContextMenu, column.Name, column.Visible);
}

private void AddContextMenuItem(ContextMenu contextMenu,
                                string columnName,
                                bool visible)
{
    var menuItem = new MenuItem(columnName,
        new EventHandler(this.ContextMenu_onClick)) { Checked = visible };
    contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
}
```

Then when the the menu option is toggled change the `Visible` property of the column.

```
private void ContextMenu_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clicked = sender as MenuItem;
    if (clicked != null)
    {
        // Update the state of the context menu
        clicked.Checked = !clicked.Checked;

        // Update the visibity of this column
        this.dataGridView.Columns[clicked.Text].Visible = clicked.Checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to controll which coulmns to get displayed when the application is running. I want to right klick at the top of the gridview and choose wich columns to display from a list. There got to be a way to that.

Comment: I will try run it later. Thnx very much :D

Comment: I cant get this working :S, I get errors with the foreach loop and I dont get eny menus on the form when I run the application :S

Comment: @Erik - what errors do you get? I did extract the code from my application so there's a chance I missed something. You'll have to bind the right click to the context menu as well - which I haven't shown.

Comment: If I copy and paste your code into my application it dose not work, first I must create an instanse of ContextMenu context = new ContextMenu(), then in the foreach loop the error is: The object dose not contain a definition for Name and Visible. What do I have to do? Iam little bit confused :D

Comment: Is it possible to bind the ContextMenu to the top of the DGV and not to entire DGV? I mean that the ContextMenu shows up only when I right klick at the top of the DGV where coulmns are?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` property--set to `false`.  Explicitly configure the columns you want, and you're good to go.

Comment: I was wondering if there is eny way to choose the coulumns when I run the application. I whant to right klick at the top of the gridview and choose the coulmns I want from a list. Is there any way to that?